# Nested Scroll Areas

Tags: wpf, layout, scroll

I creating a control for WPF, and I have a question for you WPF gurus out there.

I want my control to be able to expand to fit a resizable window.

In my control, I have a list box that I want to expand with the window. I also have other controls around the list box (buttons, text, etc).

I want to be able to set a minimum size on my control, but I want the window to be able to be sized smaller by creating scroll bars for viewing the control.

This creates nested scroll areas: One for the list box and a ScrollViewer wrapping the whole control.

Now, if the list box is set to auto size, it will never have a scroll bar because it is always drawn full size within the ScrollViewer.

I only want the control to scroll if the content can't get any smaller, otherwise I don't want to scroll the control; instead I want to scroll the list box inside the control.

How can I alter the default behavior of the ScrollViewer class? I tried inheriting from the ScrollViewer class and overriding the MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride classes, but I couldn't figure out how to measure and arrange the child properly. It appears that the arrange has to affect the ScrollContentPresenter somehow, not the actual content child.

Any help/suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Great question. We've run into a very similar problem ourselves.

Answer (score 14):

I've created a class to work around this problem:

```
public class RestrictDesiredSize : Decorator
{
    Size lastArrangeSize = new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity);

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Measure: " + constraint);
        base.MeasureOverride(new Size(Math.Min(lastArrangeSize.Width, constraint.Width),
                                      Math.Min(lastArrangeSize.Height, constraint.Height)));
        return new Size(0, 0);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Arrange: " + arrangeSize);
        if (lastArrangeSize != arrangeSize) {
            lastArrangeSize = arrangeSize;
            base.MeasureOverride(arrangeSize);
        }
        return base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeSize);
    }
}
```

It will always return a desired size of (0,0), even if the containing element wants to be bigger.
Usage:

```
<local:RestrictDesiredSize MinWidth="200" MinHeight="200">
     <ListBox />
</local>
```

Comment: Clean, simple, elegant solution

Answer (score 2):

You problem arises, because `Control`s within a `ScrollViewer` have virtually unlimited space available. Therefore your inner `ListBox` thinks it can avoid scrolling by taking up the complete height necessary to display all its elements. Of course in your case that behaviour has the unwanted side effect of exercising the outer `ScrollViewer` too much.

The objective therefore is to get the `ListBox` to use the **visible** height within the `ScrollViewer` iff there is enough of it and a certain minimal height otherwise. To achieve this, the most direct way is to inherit from `ScrollViewer` and override [`MeasureOverride()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.measureoverride.aspx) to pass an appropriately sized `availableSize` (that is the given `availableSize` blown up to the minimal size instead of the "usual" infinity) to the `Visual`s found by using [`VisualChildrenCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.visualchildrencount.aspx) and [`GetVisualChild(int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.getvisualchild.aspx).

Comment: +1 for the explanation regarding the unlimited available space.

Answer (score 2):

I used [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/141502/daniel)s solution. That works great. Thank you.

Then I added two boolean dependency properties to the decorator class: `KeepWidth` and `KeepHeight`. So the new feature can be suppressed for one dimension.

This requires a change in `MeasureOverride`:

```
protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
{
    var innerWidth = Math.Min(this._lastArrangeSize.Width, constraint.Width);
    var innerHeight = Math.Min(this._lastArrangeSize.Height, constraint.Height);
    base.MeasureOverride(new Size(innerWidth, innerHeight));

    var outerWidth = KeepWidth ? Child.DesiredSize.Width : 0;
    var outerHeight = KeepHeight ? Child.DesiredSize.Height : 0;
    return new Size(outerWidth, outerHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While I wouldn't recommend creating a UI that requires outer scroll bars you can accomplish this pretty easily:

```
<Window
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  >    
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ListBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" MinWidth="200"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="Button1"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="Button2"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Content="Button3"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

I don't really recommend this. WPF provides exceptional layout systems, like Grid, and you should try to allow the app to resize itself as needed. Perhaps you can set a MinWidth/MinHeight on the window itself to prevent this resizing?

Comment: The difficulty is that I want to be able to shrink the window below the minimum size without cropping the controls.

Comment: Do you *have* to let the window shrink down below that minimum size? What are you trying to accomplish by allowing that?

Comment: No, don't have to, but the whole problem goes away if I don't. I want to shrink below minimum size to allow flexible layouts. I'm actually building an app that contains "window-like" controls that can be sized and positioned.

Comment: Then the above code should work for you. Just make sure your pieces are in the right "*" and "Auto" sized columns, and make sure the outer ScrollViewer is using "Auto" for Horizontal/VerticalScrollbarVisibility.

Comment: And, you may want to leave those as always "Visible" to prevent the jump when one needs to be visible suddenly.

Comment: Your solution does not work. Add a few items to the ListBox and you'll see that the listbox never becomes scrollable; it's always the parent ScrollViewer that will scroll.
I think the Josh G was (like me) looking for a solution where the outer ScrollViewer only will be used only if necessary for MinWidth/MinHeight.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in the code-behind that sets the ListBox's MaxHeight to the height of whatever control is containing it and other controls.  If the Listbox has any controls/margins/padding above or below it, subtract their heights from the container height assigned to MaxHeight.  Call this method in the main windows "loaded" and "window resize" event handlers.

This should give you the best of both worlds.  You are giving the ListBox a "fixed" size that will cause it to scroll in spite of the fact that the main window has its own scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

for 2 ScrollViewer

```
   public class ScrollExt: ScrollViewer
{
    Size lastArrangeSize = new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity);

    public ScrollExt()
    {

    }
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        base.MeasureOverride(new Size(Math.Min(lastArrangeSize.Width, constraint.Width),
                                      Math.Min(lastArrangeSize.Height, constraint.Height)));
        return new Size(0, 0);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
    {
        if (lastArrangeSize != arrangeSize)
        {
            lastArrangeSize = arrangeSize;
            base.MeasureOverride(arrangeSize);
        }
        return base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeSize);
    }
}
```

code:

```
  <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Background="Beige" Width="600" Text="Example"/>
            <Grid Grid.Column="1" x:Name="grid">
                    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="25" Background="Green">
                    <local:ScrollExt HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <Grid Width="10000" Margin="25" Background="Red" />
                    </local:ScrollExt>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up combining [Daniels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1571972/1011688) answer and [Heiner's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9988974/1011688) answer. I decided to post the entire solution to make it easier for people to adopt this if needed. Here's my decorator class:

```
public class RestrictDesiredSizeDecorator : Decorator
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty KeepWidth;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty KeepHeight;

    #region Dependency property setters and getters
    public static void SetKeepWidth(UIElement element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(KeepWidth, value);
    }

    public static bool GetKeepWidth(UIElement element)
    {
        return (bool)element.GetValue(KeepWidth);
    }

    public static void SetKeepHeight(UIElement element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(KeepHeight, value);
    }

    public static bool GetKeepHeight(UIElement element)
    {
        return (bool)element.GetValue(KeepHeight);
    }
    #endregion

    private Size _lastArrangeSize = new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity);

    static RestrictDesiredSizeDecorator()
    {
        KeepWidth = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            nameof(KeepWidth),
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(RestrictDesiredSizeDecorator));

        KeepHeight = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            nameof(KeepHeight),
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(RestrictDesiredSizeDecorator));
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Measure: " + constraint);

        var keepWidth = GetValue(KeepWidth) as bool? ?? false;
        var keepHeight = GetValue(KeepHeight) as bool? ?? false;

        var innerWidth = keepWidth ? constraint.Width : Math.Min(this._lastArrangeSize.Width, constraint.Width);
        var innerHeight = keepHeight ? constraint.Height : Math.Min(this._lastArrangeSize.Height, constraint.Height);
        base.MeasureOverride(new Size(innerWidth, innerHeight));

        var outerWidth = keepWidth ? Child.DesiredSize.Width : 0;
        var outerHeight = keepHeight ? Child.DesiredSize.Height : 0;

        return new Size(outerWidth, outerHeight);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Arrange: " + arrangeSize);

        if (_lastArrangeSize != arrangeSize)
        {
            _lastArrangeSize = arrangeSize;
            base.MeasureOverride(arrangeSize);
        }

        return base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeSize);
    }
}
```

and here's how I use it in the xaml:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Whatever />

        <decorators:RestrictDesiredSizeDecorator MinWidth="100" KeepHeight="True">
            <TextBox
                Text="{Binding Comment, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                Height="Auto"
                MaxHeight="360"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                AcceptsReturn="True"
                AcceptsTab="True"
                TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"
                />
        </decorators:RestrictDesiredSizeDecorator>

        <Whatever />
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer
```

The above creates a textbox that will grow vertically (until it hits MaxHeight) but will match the parent's width without growing the outer ScrollViewer. Resizing the window/ScrollViewer to less than 100 wide will force the outer ScrollViewer to show the horizontal scroll bars. Other controls with inner ScrollViewers can be used as well, including complex grids.